# Google Cloud: How to list granted permission for user or service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Is it possible to get a list of all permissions that have been granted (specifically or transitively) to a user or GCP service account, ideally filtered by resource, through `gcloud` or the web UI?

Answer (score 8):

If I understood your question correctly, you can see them in the "**IAM & admin**" console. In the "**IAM**" tab:

- With "*View by: MEMBERS*" option, you would be able to see a list of all members (users and services accounts) and the roles granted to them.
- In "*View by: ROLES*" there is a list of all roles and (if expanded) all users/service accounts that have that role.

In case you want to know more about those roles, in the "**Roles**" tab (inside "*IAM & admin*"), you can click on them and see exactly what permissions each one has.

Currently there is no `gcloud` command for listing all granted permissions as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions), so I filed a [public Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118365351) on your behalf. Lastly, this is [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/) for the `gcloud iam` commands.

If you feel like learning more about IAM, these is the [overview and documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/) for the product.

Comment: Thank you, what I'm looking for is a list of permissions that one specific user/service account has been granted. From what I can see, the IAM & admin page doesn't list transitive grants. E.g. if I'm a member of group1, I can see the grants to group1, but I can't search by my own username and see those grants. Also, I'm not able to see grants in other projects if I don't have resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy on that project. Basically I'd like something like https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions that tests all possible permissions, if possible through gcloud.

Comment: Currently that's not possible, so I filed a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118365351) on your behalf. You can follow updates there. I edited my answer for it to be clearer.

Comment: thank you! marking this as the answer for now, will update if/when this feature becomes available.

Comment: No prob at all! If you feel there's something I forgot or something you wanna add, feel free to add a comment in the FR.

Comment: Has anyone figured it out yet? @Iñigo, I am also trying to find out how to list permissions for a user/group/service account and to what all projects?

Comment: Thanks @Iñigo! The proper fix has been linked in your Feature Request and thanks to it I wrote my answer below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70034341/2693875 .

Answer (score 3):

You can use Asset Search to find all the roles (not permissions) a user is granted with directly (not transitively) upon various resources within a given scope (i.e., an organization, folder, or project).

This allows you to search across projects and resources. However, you must have the cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies permission upon the scope.

Here is a sample command:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="policy:foo@bar.com" | egrep "role:|resource:"
```

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies

Supported resource types: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types

More details: [How to list, find, or search iam policies across services (APIs), resource types, and projects in google cloud platform (GCP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480678/how-to-list-find-or-search-iam-policies-across-services-apis-resource-types)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Policy Analyzer** feature of the Cloud Asset Inventory.

Under the web UI there is a query template called "[What access does my employee (or terminated employee) have?](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/analyzer/query;templateId=ACCESS_TERMINATED_EMPLOYEE)" that seems to fit your needs exactly.

See the official ["Analyzing IAM policies" docs](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/analyzing-iam-policy) for more info.