# How to list, find, or search iam policies across services (APIs), resource types, and projects in google cloud platform (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-resource-manager

In Google Cloud Platform (GCP), you can only get the IAM policy for a specific resource by calling getIamPolicy (get-iam-policy in gcloud).

Is there a way to list, search, list, search, or find IAM policies across resources, services, or projects?

This is needed to answer questions like:

- What roles does a service account have?
- Which resources are shared publicly?
- Do policies contain deleted users?
- Does a user still appear in any policies after they leave my company?
- Does a user has a given role?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use search-all-iam-policies to search all the IAM policies across services, resource types, projects within a project, folder, or organization.

To browse policies in a project with number 123 (note that only policies for the [listed resource types](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types) are supported):

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=projects/123
```

Who has the role Owner in my org?

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/456 --query="policy:roles/owner"
```

Who can change project IAM policies in my org?

```
--query='policy.role.permissions:resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy'
```

Which roles does an account has?

```
--query="policy:123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Which resources are shared publicly?

```
--query="policy:(allUsers OR allAuthenticatedUsers)"
```

Are there deleted accounts in policies?

```
--query="policy:deleted"
```

Does amy@bar.com appear in any policy?

```
--query="policy:amy@bar.com"
```

Does amy@bar.com have the Owner role?

```
--query="policy:(roles/owner amy@bar.com)"
```

How to find all the IAM policies for a given resource type (e.g., projects)?

```
--query="policy:roles/owner resource://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects"
```

Is there any gmail account having the role Owner?

```
`--query="policy:(roles/owner *gmail*)"
```

You can change the scope to a folder or a project.

To use the command, you must:

- Enable [Cloud Asset API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudasset.googleapis.com), and
- Have `cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies` permission upon the scope, which is included in these roles:

  - roles/cloudasset.viewer
  - roles/cloudasset.owner
  - roles/viewer
  - roles/editor
  - roles/owner

Documentation:

- More gcloud examples: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies-samples
- Guide: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies
- API reference: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/iamPolicies/searchAll
- Searchable resource types: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types