# How to get GCP "iampolicy" information in .CSV format with project ID?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am not good at programming. I am trying to generate csv report from GCP cloud account. I need information about number of projects created in account and it's owner, IAM role and member etc.

I did try with bash script and I received output in json.

**CODE**

```
#!/bin/bash
for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
do
  echo "ProjectId:  $project"
  iampolicy=$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy "$project" --format json")
  echo "$iampolicy"
  printf '%s\n' $iampolicy | paste -sd ',' >> file.csv
done
```

**Output**

```
ProjectId:  test-project1-xyz
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:123@gmail.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/owner"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "xyz=",
  "version": 1
}
```

Currently I m getting same json output data in the file.csv file.

**Expected Output**

*File.csv*

```
Project ID  Members-Email   Role
xyz         xyz              xyz
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "ID,Name,Member,Role"
gcloud projects list --format="csv[no-heading](projectId,name)" |\
while IFS="," read -r ID NAME
do
  POLICY=$(\
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${ID} \
    --flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
    --format="csv[no-heading](bindings.members,bindings.role)")
  # Prefix ${PROJECT} to each line in the policy
  for LINE in ${POLICY}
  do
    echo ${ID},${NAME},${LINE}
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Project-ID,Member,Role"
for PROJECT in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
do
  POLICY=$(\
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
    --flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
    --format="csv[no-heading](bindings.members,bindings.role)")
  # Prefix ${PROJECT} to each line in the policy
  for LINE in ${POLICY}
  do
    echo ${PROJECT},${LINE}
  done
done
```

I forget the way to split the `Member` (`type:email`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies permission upon the org that contains all the projects, you can achieve your goal using one command:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies \
--query='resource:cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects' \
--flatten=policy.bindings[].members[] \
--format='csv(resource, policy.bindings.role, policy.bindings.members)' \
--scope=organizations/123
```

Use your organization number instead of 123.

You can find more details in another thread:
[How to list, find, or search iam policies across services (APIs), resource types, and projects in google cloud platform (GCP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480678/how-to-list-find-or-search-iam-policies-across-services-apis-resource-types)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

> project_data.csv

gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId, name, createTime.date(tz=LOCAL))" >whole_project_details.txt



echo project_id, project_name, project_time >project_data.csv

while read project_details

do

project_id=`echo $project_details | awk '{print $1}'`

project_name=`echo  $project_details | awk '{print $2}'`

project_time=`echo $project_details | awk '{print $3}'`

echo $project_id, $project_name, $project_time >> project_data.csv

done < whole_project_details.txt
```

This will provide details of GCP project in CSV format, ProjectID, ProjectName and Date/Time